# Office 2007 switch to English language

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, language-pack

One of our costumers has purchased a non-English version of MS Office 2007, and he wants to switch the whole suite to English interface.

Is that possible? If yes, does anyone have a link to it?

Answer (score 2):

Just had a quick Google to see what I could find. Not much. Three things I found:

Care of [this page](http://forums.techarena.in/office-setup/986320.htm):

> Go to the Start Menu and click on
>   Microsoft Office / Microsoft Office
>   Tools / Microsoft Office 2007 Language
>   Settings. If the first tab is called
>   "Display Language" and English is
>   listed, then you already have a copy
>   of English Office installed on your
>   machine. Switch to English, click OK,
>   and reboot your apps.

I would look at what registry settings Group Policy changes for [User interface language](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179091(office.12).aspx) and then apply that to the user's computer.

Otherwise you might want to track down the Office 2007 version of [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/office-language-packs-FX101825698.aspx).

Comment: I'll check that and post a reply

Answer (score 2):

I have discussed this in-details in [my post here.](http://kmonsoor.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/install-english-language-pack-of-microsoft-office-2007-enterprise-korean-version-or-whatever-step-by-step/)

In short, You have to :
1. download your desired language pack
2. Install that
3. Go to Office's setting & then select  as default.